# Which functors $\bf Cat \to Cat$ preserve $\mathbb D$-filtrancy?

Tags: ct.category-theory

In the following, I refer to [ABLR] as the paper [A classification of accessible categories](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.28.3481&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Adamek, Borceux, Lack and Rosicki.

Doodling with symbols, and studying the aforementioned article, I began pondering: are there sensible conditions on a 2-functor $\bf Cat \to Cat$ which ensure that it sends $\mathbb D$-filtered categories (in the sense of [ABRL], for a fixed doctrine $\mathbb D$) to $\mathbb D$-filtered categories?

As it turns out easily, if $\bf C$ is filtered and cofiltered (in the classical sense, i.e. $\mathbb D$-filtered for $\mathbb D$ = {finite diagrams}), then the twisted arrow category of $\bf C$ is again filtered, so that for each presentable object $K\in\bf K$ of a finitely complete category the functor ${\bf K}(K,-)$ will preserve all coends of functors $F \colon {\bf C}^{op} \times\bf C \to K$.

This is quite simple (and there is no problem in extending it to the $\alpha$-filtered case), but heavily relies on the explicit characterization of a filtered category; I wonder if there is a more general approach giving more general statements.